# Cannot cd into the filesystems directory in Gentoo Linux

Tags: linux, terminal, directory, gentoo

I am attempting to cd into the filesystems directory as the title suggests. I was attempting to post an image but I do not yet have the reputation to do so. Am I missing a certain command? I am guessing you just cd into it but maybe I am wrong. I made a mistake when installing my Gentoo linux and am now attempting to chroot into the filesystem directory to add a password to my su. The commands I have entered where "cd /" and afterwards "cd proc" I used the "ls" command and can see filesystems in white. But when I try to cd into it, all that happens is it says the directory does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "/proc" folder is a symbolic link to caches made by your CPU. The only user, regardless of su, or sudo executions, that can access the going ons in that folder or any of the like, is the root user.

Comment: Be REALLY careful about what you do in this folder. It is also important to note that there are exploits in the wild that can be executed by simply loading a user profile. I would make sure this won't happen by keeping a baseline of roots folder structure.

Comment: Fair enough. I suppose I will find a different way. Thanks guys!

Comment: I don't have the ability to comment on your, "Answer," so I'll comment here. Firstly, and not to chide you at all, just to help you. That's not an answer, it should be considered a comment if it's important enough to even be said. Secondly, good show mate, I'm putting this under my too funny list.

Comment: So I found the answer to my problem. I was attempting to change the root password as when I first installed Gentoo it gave it no password. Just locked. So after reading the documentation, you do "passwd -d gentoo" in order to delete the accounts password so you can reset it. Where I typed "gentoo" you need to put the users name you are resetting.That is for your user password. For your actual root password it is "sudo passwd root" and you then type it in twice. I do hope this helps someone down the line possibly in my same issue.